# Amplify CLI hangs for hours when creating API models

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I have a test Android app using Amplify Auth. Everything works as expected.

I then tried updating the Auth category to add user pool groups and an admin
queries API. When running push, the build hangs at "Creating API models..." So
I closed Android Studio and tried again, with the same result.

I then removed Auth (and user pool groups, the lambda function and API) and
added Auth again (`amplify add auth`).

Here are the options I selected for the API:

```
Do you want to add User Pool Groups? Yes
? Provide a name for your user pool group: admin
? Do you want to add another User Pool Group Yes
? Provide a name for your user pool group: users
? Do you want to add another User Pool Group No
√ Sort the user pool groups in order of preference · admin, users
Do you want to add an admin queries API? Yes
? Do you want to restrict access to the admin queries API to a specific Group Yes
? Select the group to restrict access with: admin
```

When running push, it again hangs at:

```
Creating API models...
/ Updating resources in the cloud. This may take a few minutes...
```

After more than 2 hours I closed Android Studio.

Appreciate any help in solving this problem. Thanks.

Comment: I believe this is a bug. I have seen 2-3 other reports. Can you verify if the behavior is the same as in https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/5557? I also have seen the issue mentioned on Amplify's Discord server: https://discord.com/channels/705853757799399426/707329009574346754/761713439931498526

Comment: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/pull/5564 should fix this error

Comment: @Jameson thanks. its the same behavior but not when adding the REST api category. my issue is when enabling admin queries api in the auth category

Comment: @Yathi thanks. but the issue has not been resolved in my case. it still hangs.My issue is not when adding the REST api category. my issue is when enabling admin queries api in the auth category - not sure if they are the same?